# Fetch profile photo url from Instagram api

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to fetch a users instagram profile photo url for an app I'm building. I created a Meta dev account, added my app and then added the Instagram Basic Display product. A dummy account was added to Instagram Testers in order to generate an access token.

So it's possible to get *all* photo urls by making a request to `https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields={fields}&access_token={access-token}`. But there doesn't seem to be a way of identifying which one is used in the profile.

It appears that there is a `profile_pic` field, but it's on the Graph api rather than the Basic Display api which I'm using. The Graph api is for businesses or creators so is not appropriate for what I'm building.

Not sure why a publicly available asset like a profile photo is so difficult to obtain via the api.

*Note:* There may be other questions similar to this out there, but any I've found have been older and on a depreciated version of the api. It's changed a lot recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to query the Instagram API in the usual way as you might expect.

For a great alternative, see [instagram-private-api](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api) that does the job. You can see it's implementation [here](https://github.com/yasinatesim/instagram-fullsize-picture) and test it live [here](https://instagram-fullsize-picture.yasinatesim.vercel.app/).

Comment: It is asking for admin password to test it! What is the password?

Comment: The admin password request is a new feature and that is not my project. The author must have added it to prevent abuse. Pity.

Answer (score 0):

You can get publicly available assets like the profile photo once are logged in. Try [www.instagram.com/{username}/channel/?__a=1](http://www.instagram.com/%7Busername%7D/channel/?__a=1) and get the data from profile_pic_url or profile_pic_url_hd fields.

```
"profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.fkul10-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/237125289_314538050357301_4146672331065148847_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fkul10-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=bFSJzUFbs6EAX9eZnpD&edm=AAWvnRQBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT8FiYOqxVuxvzPvfKClC7cm5IrLszF2ctooM08-_dVUQw&oe=6202628B&_nc_sid=e7738c",
  "profile_pic_url_hd": "https://instagram.fkul10-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s320x320/237125289_314538050357301_4146672331065148847_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fkul10-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=bFSJzUFbs6EAX9eZnpD&edm=AAWvnRQBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT9gj3HCB2OY7c6fYyaxik15mwOKu4bMM7siim1coR4Axw&oe=620263B3&_nc_sid=e7738c",
  "requested_by_viewer": false,
  "should_show_category": false,
  "should_show_public_contacts": false,
  "username": "waqas_obeidy",
  "connected_fb_page": null,
```

Comment: Can it be done without logging in though? I was hoping to use an `access_token` to verify the user as generally advised in the documentation. Not sure how logging in works via a third-party app - can you elaborate?

Comment: Also if you could link where that is in the docs, it would be very helpful.

Comment: The url redirects to instagram login page. Have you find any other solution using the graph.instagram.com ?

Comment: You need to programmatically login with this approach. Don't bother though, it's a dead end and you will be blocked in the end anyways. I would suggest using `instagram-private-api` as mentioned in the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Instagram bizarrely do not provide any standard way of accessing a users profile picture.

The answer Waqas gave was the correct general approach, but requires user to be logged in and is prone to being blocked by Instagram if made with any frequency.

The solution I arrived at involved programatically logging into Instagram using a `csrf` token that was obtained separately. Then saving the cookie to Firestore for use in future logins so Instagram does not ban the account making the request. Another call to Instagram at the address Waqas gave and using the cookie obtained previously allowed the `profile_pic_url_hd` value taken from the JSON. Finally, another call to Instagram using the url of the profile pic in order to save the photo itself to Firestore.

*Edit 17/09/22:* [Here](https://github.com/yasinatesim/instagram-fullsize-picture) is a publicly-available standalone app that gets the full size instagram profile picture and displays it.

Comment: So basically what you’re suggesting is that get user session id from the cookies and pass it along with other url while making requests to it, right?